# When are extremely low quality questions with links spam?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, spam

Some time ago I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841257/16217248) question which is no more than *'How can I make a site like this <link>'*. When I saw this, I thought it was so low quality it was hard to believe it was a serious question and was more likely a spam post. However, my spam flag on the post was declined. When are questions with barely more than a link spam or not?

Comment: Just found in Meta (SE) what looks to be the same post --> https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382774/289691 SE is under a SPAM attack :P

Comment: What make even more fair your flag declination clarification request. Anyway, if you already have several accepted flags, don't take too serious a single flag declination.

Comment: If this is your first flag declination don't waste your time and mods time on that... just be patient it's very likely that soon you will get an answer or links to the related help articles and questions (maybe I will add some later, right now I go for coffee refill)

Comment: <UPDATE> The referred question is now deleted.</UPDATE>The referred question is now closed, has score of -10 and 2 delete votes. Looking at the history, it shows that the question was in two review queues that were marked as invalidated very likely because the closing of the question. Please take a look to the tag wikis of [meta-tag:declined-flags] and [meta-tag:spam] as well the frequent questions of both tags to learn more about how a flag might be declined, what is considered spam here about anecdotes of similar situations.

Comment: *"I thought it was so low quality it was hard to believe it was a serious question"* ... why? It is low quality, but it reads like a serious question to me. A seriously lazy question, and I fully expect people who do not understand Stack Overflow to go ahead and post them. To be honest in my own web development efforts I frequently find myself looking at other sites and ask myself the question "how!?". But I don't go echo that on Stack Overflow, I go look at the page source instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a thorny problem. There is no simple answer, but here are some guideposts.

- If you discover undisclosed affiliation, it's technically spam. Sometimes these posts are made in good faith, and so I personally tend to hold back on actually flagging as spam if it's a first offense. See also [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).
- As mentioned in the promotion guideline I linked in the previous bullet point, *repeated* undisclosed promotion should probably deserve a spam flag, and probably a moderator flag to boot. (You can't do both, so probably prioritize the mod flag, and explain in more detail why you are flagging, with links to pertinent posts etc.)
- If the content is plagiarized, it's red-flaggable. Probably leave a comment to identify the original source. Some spammers go to great lengths to obscure the original source (for example, by changing some words into synonyms, not realizing that synonyms very rarely mean *exactly* the same thing and thus making the text hard or even impossible to understand in the process).

  **Update:** A dedicated *Plagiarism* flag is now available as of March 2023 and should be used for plagiarized content.
- At the other end of the spectrum, it's often not possible to say whether an isolated VLQ (very low quality) post is malicious or merely incompetent. Some spammers try to exploit this, and post "innocuous" questions just to link to their sites. When we discover systematic abuse, we flag them all as spam; investigations include looking for basically identical posts, and checking various features of the linked sites. For example, if they are all on the same IP address, that's a pretty clear indicator (though it's not unheard of for large ISPs to host thousands of different domain names on the same IP address, and so this might still risk some false positives).

As a regular in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), the volunteer anti-spam squad on Stack Exchange, I look at spam dozens or hundreds of times every day, and even then it's sometimes hard to articulate any actionable guidance for when exactly something moves from "smells funny" to "smells bad".

When a post is merely closed as VLQ or etc, but there is some reason to suspect that it might have been a spam post actually, I sometimes post a [del-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del-pls) in the [SOCVR room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) with an explanation of why I feel the post should be removed, just to be on the safe side. These posts will typically [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) after 10 days, but if it's actually spam, you don't want it to stay up that long.

Comment: How do users who can't see deleted posts know if undisclosed affiliation is a first time offense or if it's repeated?

Comment: We have an archive of deleted spam at https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/ though of course, this only contains copies of the spam posts which were reported to Charcoal / Smoke Detector in the first place. Perhaps see also https://charcoal-se.org/ for an overview of our operations.

Comment: *If the content is plagiarized, it's red-flaggable* I don't follow. Spam with plagiarism is essentially the same as spam without plagiarism, right? And if something is plagiarized but isn't spam, a custom flag is much more likely to get the intent across.

Comment: Sure, but plagiarized spam is sometimes hard to identify as spam until you find the source of the text. Then it's often quite obvious.

Comment: [A particularly obvious example of plagiarized spam](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/392458).